# Hbase single node installation Error

Tags: hbase

Not able to run HBASE getting error

> Master Server Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop hbase.util.HBaseConfTool
>   Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKServerTool
>   Regional server error
>   Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer

Done the configuration by adding into `HBASE-SITE.xml` also Done setting java into `hbase-env.sh` still not able to run hbase, can any one help with this?

I'm using:

- java - 8
- hbase - 1.2.6
- ubuntu - os

Comment: maybe your java classpath is missing the region_server maybe set hbase_home to point to the libraries?

Comment: Hi Paul thanks for support,This is what my hbase home                    #HBASE_HOME
export HBASE_HOME=/usr/local/hbase
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HBASE_HOME/bin:$PATH
export HBASE_REGIONSERVERS=$HBASE_HOME/conf/regionservers
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true                                                                     >Still Not Working ?Any suggestions?